# Stop specific people (or everyone) from getting notifications when I post a comment on or like a page's post on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-privacy

Is this possible?

If I'm posting a comment reply to someone on a news story, I don't necessarily want it to be going out to my friends; they're not interested in my ramblings or opinions on current affairs, if I wanted them to be notified, I would make a status.

As a consequence of this, I rarely post comments when otherwise I might, as I don't want to be bothering my friends with a conversation the probably have no interest in.

I'm also concerned it's will reduce my visibility, because I'll have such low interaction with these bullshit notifications that people get that when I actually make a post I want my friends to be notified about, it won't pop up in their news feeds.